# Using +45 for tel protocol on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have a phone number that looks like this `+4512345678`, but I cannot call it from code due to the +. 
It is needed if I call from another country e.g. from Sweden to Denmark.

How can I do this in iOS?

At the moment I am using `tel://+4512345678`, but it will not open the link.

Comment: Are you testing on a real device or in the simulator?

Comment: I am testing on both

Answer (score 0):

There should be no `//` in the URL:

```
"tel:+4512345678"
```

See [RFC 2806](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2806.txt)

Comment: @LasseMadsen Are you sure you have a valid phone number?

Comment: Yes, if I write it on my phone and make a call, it calls the other user correctly

Comment: @LasseMadsen Are you sure there are no spaces or other invalid symbols?

Comment: Yes, I am sure it is only +, the country code and the number